# Removing strings in a series of headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a number of columns in a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[1990],'State Income of Alabama':[1], 
                   'State Income of Washington':[2],
                   'State Income of Arizona':[3]})
```

All headers have the same number of strings and all have the exact same strings with exactly one white space between the State's name.

I want to take out the strings 'State Income of ' and leave the state in tact as a new header for the set so they just all read:

```
Alabama  Washington  Arizona
1        2           3
```

I've tried using the replace columns function in Python like:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('State Income of ', '')
```

But this isn't giving me the desired output.

Comment: Why isn't your code producing your desired output?

Comment: @blacksite Nope, `df.columns` is an index and it actually does have `str` accessor .

Comment: @RafaelC, huh, TIL. Thanks. Deleting my other comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution, not in place:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split()[-1])
```

or in place:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split()[-1], inplace = True)
```

Comment: You could add `inplace=True` to make it in place

Answer (score 2):

Your way works for me, but there are alternatives:

One way is to split your column names and take the last word:

```
df.columns = [i.split()[-1] for i in df.columns]
>>> df
   Alabama  Arizona  Washington
0        1        3           2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re` module for this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'State Income of Alabama':[1], 
...                    'State Income of Washington':[2],
...                    'State Income of Arizona':[3]})
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> df.columns = [re.sub('State Income of ', '', col) for col in df]
>>> df
   Alabama  Washington  Arizona
0        1           2        3
```

`re.sub('State Income of', '', col)` will replace any occurrence of 'State Income of' with an empty string (with "nothing," effectively) in the string `col`.